# Ag Grid - How to set the width and height of a standard cell editor to the full width and height of the cell

Tags: ag-grid

I have a standard cell editor and when I am in edit mode the width and the height  of the cell editor is not the full width and height of the cell.

[image]

Should I overwrite the styles or is there any flag in the configuration to turn off this effect?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. If you look at the DOM, you'll see `ag-grid` adds a wrapper div around all custom editors, and it's actually that div that is the problem. I solved it by adding this to my global CSS:

```css
.ag-react-container {
    /* 
     * This class is used on divs automatically inserted by AgGrid around custom cell editors.
     * Without this, I don't know of another way of ensuring that the underlying <input> can take
     * up 100% of the height of the parent cell, if it so chooses to.
     */
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It would be work if the editor was a custom editor. But I have the problem with a built-in editors. Here there is no wrapper div:

`<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="52" col-id="myColumn" class="ag-cell ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus ag-cell-inline-editing" style="width: 286px;left: 573px;"><input class="ag-cell-edit-input" type="text"></div>`

Comment: Does targeting the `ag-cell-inline-editing` class work?

Comment: Apparently they have removed this wrapper div in [v27.0.0](https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=27.0.0) and has gone for a [React based rendering](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/27.0.0/react-data-grid/reactui/) mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to achieve this is to only modify the inline style editor css:

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-cell.ag-cell-inline-editing{
 height: 100%;
}
```