# ag-grid CellEditor cell height not correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid with react 16.12.0.

I have this column defintion:

```
   const columnsAuszeichnungenn = [{
        headerName: "Award",
        field: "auszeichnungsname",
        resizable: true,
        sortingOrder: ['asc']
    }, {
        headerName: "From",
        field: "von",
        resizable: true,
        editable: true,
        cellEditorFramework: CellEditorOnlyNumbers,
        onCellValueChanged: (params: any) => {
            //Check if the user has changed the value
            if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
                doSomething(params.newValue, "von", params.data);
            }
        },
        cellStyle: {'white-space': 'normal'},
    }];
```

CellEditorOnlyNumbers:

```
const CellEditorOnlyNumbers: React.FC<Props> = (props, ref) => {

    const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(props.value);

    function onBlurcheckInput(e: any): void {
        const value = e.currentTarget.value.trim();
        /*Zuerst überprüfen wir, ob wir vlt nicht nur in das Textfeld hinein geklickt
        haben und ohne etwas zu machen wieder raus gegangen sind, deshalb erste if*/
        if (value !== props.value && !error) {
            props.api.stopEditing();
        }
    }

    function onchangeCheck(e: any): void {
        const value = e.currentTarget.value.trim();
        let isError = false;
        if (value === "" || isNaN(value)) {
            //Es ist keine Zahl -> Fehler
            isError = true;
        }

        setValue(value);
        setError(isError);
    }


    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        return {
            getValue: () => {
                if (error) {
                    //return initial value
                    return props.value;
                } else {
                    return parseInt(value);
                }
            }
        };
    });

    return (
        <>
            <FormControl
                error={error}>
                <Input
                    onBlur={onBlurcheckInput}
                    onChange={(e: any) => onchangeCheck(e)}
                    value={value}
                    type="number"
                />
            </FormControl>
        </>
    );
};

export default forwardRef(CellEditorOnlyNumbers);
```

And I have this behaviour:
[image]

The size of the cell is not correct. I would like to make the cell editor the same height as the parent row.
Sadly I have no clue where to start. Can anybody show me a working example or point me to the correct direction.

//EDIT
Found a solution here, with overwriting css:
[Change cell height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52894933/ag-grid-how-to-set-the-width-and-height-of-a-standard-cell-editor-to-the-full)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your editor Input style like this:

add this in your css, your css must be last css in your code.
this is depend on your ag-grid theme, this sample work with ag-theme-balham theme class, then if you want to change theme, you have to change this line:

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-cell-inline-editing {
  height: 100%;
}
```

then use this:

```
<Input
   style={{position:"absolute", width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
   onBlur={onBlurcheckInput}
   onChange={(e: any) => onchangeCheck(e)}
   value={value}
   type="number"
/>
```

or change to this:

```
<div style={{height: "100%", position:"absolute"}}>
   <Input
      style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
      onBlur={onBlurcheckInput}
      onChange={(e: any) => onchangeCheck(e)}
      value={value}
      type="number"
   />
</div>
```

sample-double click Age field and see height : [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-demo-xgm4r)

`> Just sample and no real editor`

Comment: This isn`t working. It has the same behaviour as default. Look at my modfieid sandbox-example (changed only row height to 50. But the row height of the edited field does not fit: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-demo-9598q

Comment: Answer updated, css added and demo updated see answer DEMO

Comment: it is working with the css alone as well :-) We do not need the div style height 100% position absolute ...